# SQL Server Edition comparison - 2005 vs 2008 vs 2008R2 vs 2012

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone know any site/link which can provide what were the major upgrade in SQL Server Edition (From Administration, Development and Business Intelligence aspect) - 2005 vs 2008 vs 2008R2 vs 2012

Regards

Comment: How about try google :) sample result: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500435(v=sql.100).aspx)?

Answer (score 8):

Each release has a What's new section:

- [What's New in SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500435.aspx)
- [What's New (SQL Server 2008 R2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500435%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [What's New (SQL Server 2008)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500435%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)
- [What's New in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170363%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)